# How to remove set of special characters (see attachment)

Tags: sed, awk, grep

This characters is special I can not put in code because the forum not support it. Here is how it looks in code format: [32;1m

The cube (first character) is arrow to left in file (see links above).
Here is the picture of character how it look.See the file: http://www.dodaj.rs/f/2u/ar/3B1Q7J4Q/sample.jpg
And here is attachement of file it consist what I want to remove: http://hotfile.com/dl/124448134/58e08a0/File.log.html
Here is the complete file:

```
[32;1m/var/log/daemon.log file is rotated1...[0m
[32;1m/var/log/daemon.log file is rotated2...[0m
[37;1m/var/log/daemon.log file is rotated3...[0m
[35;1m/var/log/daemon.log file is rotated3...[0m 
[33;1mhello[0m
[33;1mthis is sample[0m 
[33;1mwhats up?[0m
```

What I want is to delete everything of unnecessary characters and output to be:

```
/var/log/daemon.log file is rotated1...
/var/log/daemon.log file is rotated2...
/var/log/daemon.log file is rotated3...
/var/log/daemon.log file is rotated3...
hello
this is sample
whats up?
```

I tried to delete special characters with sed like:

```
cat File.log | sed 's/[!@#\$%^&*()]//g' | sed -e 's/37;1m//g' > output.log
```

but it do nothing.
Can someone please write me that code that make what I need?
Thx.

EDIT: After posting the post arrow can not see on forum...

Comment: All of your external links are broken! This is why you should post relevant content here on SO.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -e 's/[[:cntrl:]]//g' -e 's/\[32;1m//g' -e 's/\[33;1m//g' -e 's/\[35;1m//g' -e 's/\[37;1m//g' -e 's/\[0m//g'
```

Comment: Man you rock it!
Thank you VERRRRYYYY much!

Comment: I do not get what is not working.
If I do 'cat File.log | sed ... | sed ...' it gives the same as 'cat File.log | sed ...'.
Could you update the question with an example that is not working.

Comment: No no. everythings OK, my fault. I delete post where I complained.
Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '[32;1m/var/log/daemon.log file is rotated1...[0m' | awk -F'1m' '{sub("\[0m","",$2);print $2}'
```

/var/log/daemon.log file is rotated1...

Comment: Thx for answer but it not working as I expect.
If I use this code to clean whole file at once then it generate me error in stdout: 

`awk: warning: escape sequence `\[' treated as plain `['

awk: (FILENAME=/tmp/CCcamVPS_temp.log FNR=1) fatal: Unmatched [ or [^: /[0m/`

I use this code in next way:

`awk -F'1m' '{sub("\[0m","",$2);print $2}' inputfile.log > outputfile.log`